# PIL - Pasting/saving image as .jpg

Tags: python, image, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I made this simple code to try to debug a bigger program that essentially does the same thing:

```
from PIL import Image

photo = Image.open('Test1.png')        #640x480
photo.paste("black",(100,100,200,200))
photo.save('Edited.jpg')
photo.close()
```

**The goal:** Working with a .png image and then converting it to (saving it as) .jpg.

I'm getting the following **error** on the *photo.save* line:

> raise IOError("decoder %s not available" % decoder_name) IOError:
>   decoder jpeg not available

Even when I try to open a .jpg file, i get the same error, but this time on the *photo.paste* line.

**What I've tried**: Uninstalled PIL through pip, installed the jpeg libs (libjpeg-dev, libfreetype6-dev, zlib1g-dev, libpng12-dev) which were already installed afterall, and reinstalled PIL. Still didn't work.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading.

**EDIT:** System info: Raspberry Pi A - Raspbian Wheezy (3.18.7+ GNU/Linux) - Python 2.7.3

Comment: What OS, python version you use?

Comment: I just tried this in Windows 7, Python 3.4.2, Pillow 2.6.1, with a .jpg from Windows' Sample Pictures folder. It worked perfectly, no errors. It must be environment-related.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. I'm on a Raspberry Pi, running Rasbian Wheezy (linux version 3.18.7+) - Python 2.7.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, firstly make sure **libjpeg-dev** has installed. After, find a shared lib, like this:

```
$ sudo find /usr/lib -iname libjpeg.so
/path/with/found/libjpeg.so
$ sudo ln -vs /path/with/found/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/
```

Thus, remove and reinstall PIL/Pillow:

```
$ sudo pip uninstall Pillow
$ sudo pip install Pillow #or $ sudo apt-get install python-imaging
```

It should be work. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you but still got the same error =/

    raise IOError("encoder %s not available" % encoder_name)
IOError: encoder jpeg not available

Comment: Try uninstall via dpkg --purge. Maybe python-imaging has been previously installed also well.

Comment: SOLVED - Thank you felipsmartins! I think what worked for me was removing the python-imaging through apt-get and then installing it again (just to make sure, I did the same thing with Pillow via pip). Anyway, it's working now, muito obrigado :)

Comment: Great! I'm sure it'll be useful for someone else.